# windows terminal preview: open windows from a previous session (in admin mode)

Tags: windows-terminal

In the **windows terminal preview**, there is an option: *"open windows from a previous session"*. **But** for some reason it doesn't work in administrator mode. I'm looking for a solution: how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in [microsoft/terminal#12240](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/discussions/12240):

> This is something that the Terminal didn't support in 1.12, it should be fixed in 1.13. See [#11222](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/11222) for the PR where this is fixed.

Comment: yes, it was me who ask the question: microsoft/terminal#12240 ;)